# How to Deploy Spring boot non-web application to Weblogic Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, weblogic

I'm developing some applications on Spring Boot, They're included one web application and three non-web applications.
With non-web applications, they're listen on message broker (RabbitMQ) and consume the message which they received. It work as a Worker. And because they are not web application I just implement `CommandLineRunner` for Spring Boot main class of Workers

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InternalworkerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InternalworkerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(InternalworkerApplication.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF); //disable spring banner
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Internal Worker running...");
    }
}
```

And now, I have to deploy my applications (include web app and non-web apps) on Weblogic Server.
With web application, just need extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and  implements `WebApplicationInitializer` to deploy it on Weblogic.
But with my non-web applications, How can I deploy it to Weblogic without implements `WebApplicationInitializer`

More advanced , I want to containerized my applications. With Tomcat, I did get it to work with run applications on each container to work together with Docker. How can I do same thing with Weblogic

Comment: Why do you want to deploy non-web apps on weblogic? Why not directly run them outside of weblogic (on same or different machine)?

Comment: Because it is requirement of client. So that, I have to deploy all my application on Weblogic server. As I know, Weblogic support one of kind applications : 

   1.  Web Application

    2. Enterprise JavaBean
    3. Resource Adapter
    4. Web Service
    5. Java EE Library
    6. Optional Package
    7. JDBC, JMS, and WLDF Modules
    8. Client Application Archive

But I dont know my workers application can match with what kind of application above without Web Application. And how to config it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy a Spring Boot (non-web) Application on Weblogic 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639266/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-non-web-application-on-weblogic-12c)

Comment: @Smile I've found it. But you can help to more details. With non-web applications and will run forever as Worker to handle heavy task. How can I config it become one of kinds as : 
2. Enterprise JavaBean 3. Resource Adapter 4. Web Service 5. Java EE Library 6. Optional Package 7. JDBC, JMS, and WLDF Modules 8. Client Application Archive